# WPF INotifyPropertyChanged without burning base class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to find a simple approach for data binding in WPF.
I'm using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and it works fine if it's implemented on an abstract base class and inherited by objects that have bound members.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static MainWindow Instance;

    private readonly Vm _vm;

    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _vm = new Vm
        {
            Button1 = new Vm.ObservableButton(button1, new List<string> { "Paused", "Logging" }, false),
            Button2 = new Vm.ObservableToggleButton(button2, new List<string> { "Log All", "Log VBA" }, false),
        };
    }

    private class Vm
    {
        public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged ([CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
            {
                var pc = PropertyChanged;
                if (pc != null)
                    pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }

        public class ObservableButton : ObservableObject
        {
            private readonly Button _b;
            private readonly List<string> _options;

            private string _content;
            public string Content
            {
                get { return _content; }
                set
                {
                    if (_content == value) return;
                    _content = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public Boolean On { set; private get; }

            public ObservableButton (Button b, List<string> options, Boolean on = true)
            {
                _b = b;
                _options = options;
                _b.Click += Click;
                On = on;
                Content = On ? _options[0] : _options[1];
            }
            public void Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                On = !On;
                Content = On ? _options[0] : _options[1];
            }

        }

        public class ObservableToggleButton : ObservableObject
        {
            private readonly ToggleButton _b;
            private readonly List<string> _options;

            private string _content;
            public string Content
            {
                get { return _content; }
                private set
                {
                    if (_content == value) return;
                    _content = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            private Boolean _on;
            public Boolean On
            {
                private get { return _on; }
                set
                {
                    if (_on == value) return;
                    _on = value;
                    Content = value ? _options[0] : _options[1];
                }
            }

            public ObservableToggleButton (ToggleButton b, List<string> options, Boolean on = true)
            {
                _b = b;
                _options = options;
                On = on;
                Content = _b.IsChecked ?? false ? _options[0] : _options[1];
            }

            public void Push ()
            {
                var peer = new ToggleButtonAutomationPeer(_b);
                var toggleProvider = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Toggle) as IToggleProvider;
                if (toggleProvider != null) toggleProvider.Toggle();
                //On = !On;
            }
        }

        public ObservableButton Button1 { get; set; }

        public ObservableToggleButton Button2 { get; set; }

        public Vm ()
        {
        }
    }
}

<Grid Margin="0,0,183,134">
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="{Binding Button1.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="button2" IsChecked="{Binding Button2.On, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Content="{Binding Button2.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="206,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

I wanted to try doing this without burning the base class though, so I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the View Model and routed the change events from the bound members, back through the single interface on the View Model. Even though the Binding Object has a reference to the Source and the correct property name, this fails silently.

I figured that it doesn't work because the Binding Object does some type checking, so I made a fake implementation on the bound properties and it works.  Here is the code for that scenario...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static MainWindow Instance;

    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel
        {
            Button1 = new ViewModel.ObservableButton(button1, new List<string> { "Paused", "Logging" }, false),
            Button2 = new ViewModel.ObservableToggleButton(button2, new List<string> { "Log All", "Log VBA" }, false),
        };
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static ViewModel _instance;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T> (T control, [CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
        {
            var pc = PropertyChanged;
            if (pc != null)
                pc(control, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

        public class ObservableButton : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged () {}

            private readonly Button _b;
            private readonly List<string> _options;

            private string _content;
            public string Content
            {
                get { return _content; }
                set
                {
                    if (_content == value) return;
                    _content = value;
                    _instance.OnPropertyChanged(this);
                }
            }

            public Boolean On { set; private get; }

            public ObservableButton (Button b, List<string> options, Boolean on = true)
            {
                _b = b;
                _options = options;
                _b.Click += Click;
                On = on;
                Content = On ? _options[0] : _options[1];
            }
            public void Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                On = !On;
                Content = On ? _options[0] : _options[1];
            }

        }

        public class ObservableToggleButton : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged () {}

            private readonly ToggleButton _b;
            private readonly List<string> _options;

            private string _content;
            public string Content
            {
                get { return _content; }
                private set
                {
                    if (_content == value) return;
                    _content = value;
                    _instance.OnPropertyChanged(this);
                }
            }

            private Boolean _on;
            public Boolean On
            {
                private get { return _on; }
                set
                {
                    if (_on == value) return;
                    _on = value;
                    Content = value ? _options[0] : _options[1];
                }
            }

            public ObservableToggleButton (ToggleButton b, List<string> options, Boolean on = true)
            {
                _b = b;
                _options = options;
                On = on;
                Content = _b.IsChecked ?? false ? _options[0] : _options[1];
            }

        }

        public ObservableButton Button1 { get; set; }

        public ObservableToggleButton Button2 { get; set; }

        public ViewModel ()
        {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }
}

    <Grid Margin="0,0,183,134">
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="{Binding Button1.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="button2" IsChecked="{Binding Button2.On, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Content="{Binding Button2.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="206,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
```

So you can see that, even though the interface on the `ObservableButton` and `ObservableToggleButton` types are still routing the change notification through their parent, the Binding Object is happy because they toe the line on type.

Is there a good reason why the the child object needs to implement the interface even though there is already everything need to complete the binding without it?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to route something through the parent? Although not directly related to the question, but your are passing control instances (Button in this case) to the view model, which defeats the whole purpose of view-view model pattern and makes it's usage useless. The whole block of code above and question itself indicates that you don't undertand that pattern (or don't want to work with it as it was designed). Maybe that should be fixed first.

Comment: @Evk, the first example is not routing anything through the parent, the signalling is directly between the buttons and the bindings via the interface that they inherited from the abstract base class.  The base class could be defined anywhere, I have it in the View Model just for compactness of the example.

Comment: to hold UI Elements in the ViewModel just totally breaks the MVVM pattern... I also think we are facing a xy Problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

I try to provide a clear example how this should be done in WPF instead of trying to fix the OP question.

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bToV" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <!--bind the text to the viewmodel content. Use a bool to visibilty converter to convert from true to Visible-->
    <TextBlock 
               Text="{Binding Path=Content}"
               Visibility="{Binding Path=IsContentVisible, Converter={StaticResource bToV}}" />
    <!--Use a two way binding to sync the IsChecked property with the viewmodel-->
    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsContentVisible,Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Content="{Binding Path=ToogleActionName}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**code behind**

to keep your project structure clear I warmly suggest to put each class in a separate file. However I put all 3 classes into one single file for easier posting.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new ContentViewModel() { Content = "foo" };
        }
    }

    public class ContentViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _toogleActionName = "turn it off";
        private bool _isContentVisible = true;
        private string _content;
        public bool IsContentVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return _isContentVisible;
            }
            set
            {
                _isContentVisible = value;

                //switch action name
                if (value)
                    ToogleActionName = "turn it off";
                else
                    ToogleActionName = "turn it on";

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Content
        {
            get
            {
                return _content;
            }
            set
            {
                _content = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string ToogleActionName
        {
            get
            {
                return _toogleActionName;
            }
            set
            {
                _toogleActionName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }


    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is showing how WPF is supposed to work with the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Ahhhh, OK: got it!  Yes!! I like that a lot.  Sorry, I'm just battling my way through learning the language at the moment and occasionally I get curious.  I know I have to study MVVM but I just haven't done it yet (I guess that's for week 3).  Technically, his doesn't answer my question but +1 for the best TLDR; I've seen so far in this ecosystem.  Everything I read is incredibly long-winded and cross-coupled...

Comment: Thanks. Good luck for your learning ;-) And don't forget: "WPF makes the hard things simple and the simple things hard"

Answer (score 0):

The problem there is that the ViewModel on the first example:

```
private class Vm
{
  ...
}
```

Does not implement INofityPropertyChanged interface, therefore whenever you say that you DataContext is "Vm", the binding would not know that a property has changed because the view model it is not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged...

And on the second example, it is working because you are implementing a INofityPropertyChanged on the view model class

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ...
}
```

Note that it doesn't matter if your child classes implements INotifyPropertyChanged if your base class doesn't implement it too and your base class is observing changes on the children and raises the changes as "its own"...

Comment: The first example works fine. The Path in the binding connects to the changing property.

Comment: @A.N. This is just wrong. You just need to implement the interface on the subclass. However as the modifier of `Vm` is `private` this should not work at all.

Comment: @Mat, really? my code runs no problem with the VM as private. I'm still struggling up a steep learning curve but it seems like assigning the VM instance to the `DataContext` object brings the View under the VM namespace.

Comment: the namespace of a object will never ever change during runtime. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx

Comment: Regarding the `private`modifier. This works. I was wrong. And it works because ìt's a subclass of `MainWindow` ->`MainWindow` can access `Vm`even tough it's `private`. This kind of subclassing is very unconventional to stay polite ;-)

Comment: @Mat, OK, but my point still stands: it works with the private access modifier which is contrary to your point.